# How can I speed up processing of thresholding using TensorFlow or PyTorch?

Tags: python, tensorflow, opencv, pytorch

I'm new to Python and am in the learning phase of image processing.
Since I need to deal with large datasets which is basically only on thresholding, TensorFlow or PyTorch may be more suitable through the usage of a GPU. Are there some related examples? What should I do?

Here's my current approach using [OpenCV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenCV).

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import os

folderDir = "C://Users/ruler/Desktop/testseg/"

total = []

with open('readme.txt', 'w') as f:
    count = 0
    for allImages in os.listdir(folderDir):

        if (allImages.startswith('TRAIN_SET') and allImages.endswith(".bmp")):

            img = cv2.imread(os.path.join(folderDir, allImages))

            gry = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

            _,blackMask = cv2.threshold(gry, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
            _, blackgreyMask = cv2.threshold(gry, 128, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
            whiteMask = cv2.bitwise_not(blackgreyMask)
            greyMask = cv2.bitwise_xor(blackMask, blackgreyMask)

            x1 = []
            y1 = []

            def verticle(mask, y, x):
                vertiPixel = 0
                while(y < mask.shape[0]):
                    if (y + 1) == mask.shape[0]:
                        break
                    else:
                        if(mask[y + 1][x] == 255):
                            vertiPixel += 1
                            y += 1
                        else:
                            break

                y1.append(vertiPixel)
                return y1

            def horizontal(mask, y, x):
                horiPixel = 0
                while(x < mask.shape[1]):
                    if (x + 1) == mask.shape[1]:
                        break
                    else:
                        if(mask[y][x + 1] == 255):
                            horiPixel += 1
                            x += 1
                        else:
                            break

                x1.append(horiPixel)
                return x1

            def mask(mask):

                for y in range (mask.shape[0]):
                    for x in range (mask.shape[1]):

                        if(mask[y][x] == 255):
                            verticle(mask, y, x)
                            horizontal(mask, y, x)

mask(blackMask)
print(np.average(y1), np.average(x1))
```

I tried to look for TensorFlow or PyTorch related for thresholding, but I did not really find it.

#### Expectation

I implemented thresholding API through TensorFlow or PyTorch to speed up image thresholding process.

Comment: Sorry, did the answer you got actually make sense? I really don't understand what it's saying at all.

Comment: @GeneralGrievance This is becoming more and more interesting, because I also don't understand 90% of his answers or his English.

Comment: @GeneralGrievance Yes I just saw it and upvoted your post. I honestly don't know what's wrong, probably lack of knowledge in English but in nowadays translation services do pretty good job.

Comment: Does the current answer have any merit? Or is it completely bogus? (Not rhetorical questions.)

Comment: @PeterMortensen If you ask me, current answer is completely useless.

Comment: The OP's gone, the question lacks details/focus, the answer is unintelligible. I'd say just Close/Delete the whole thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to understand you can implement ratios on devices for simple tasks or multiple ratios propagation, but for calculation, you can also use the TensorFlow and Keras models.

The convolution layer is what you are doing by multiple of the input image with smaller or sizes matrixes and added strides effects that can resize and remarks images from 256 x 256 to 32 x 32 with significant colors and relative position. Anyway, using program logic or implementing ratios propagation is nothing false.

Sample: Model implementation a mixing of Keras layers and function propagations.

```
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Model Initialize
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.InputLayer(input_shape=( 32, 32, 4 )),
    tf.keras.layers.Normalization(mean=3., variance=2.),
    tf.keras.layers.Normalization(mean=4., variance=6.),
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Reshape((128, 225)),
    tf.keras.layers.Bidirectional(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(96, return_sequences=True, return_state=False)),
    tf.keras.layers.Bidirectional(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(96)),
    tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(192, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(10),
])
```

Output: It is easy to create image recognitions using the TensorFlow Keras model.

[image: Sample]